# Grouping XML data into category headers based on field that contain multiple values

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to format some data that's being inputted into the Form and List module on a DotNetNuke install. It's basically a business directory - the client will fill out a form with Company Name, Address, etc. and then the data needs to be displayed within category headers. For each company, there will be a list of available categories that the client can select - and they CAN select more than one category.

I've searched for a while now and can't seem to get anything to work. I have experience editing the portion of the XSL file that outputs to HTML. Other than that, I leave the rest of the file alone because I don't have much knowledge at all about how to setup the templates, etc.

Below is the XML that is generated from the module (I only have 3 test entries added at the moment) as well as the current XSL file and how the result should be displayed on the page. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

XML:

```
<UserDefinedTable xmlns="DotNetNuke/UserDefinedTable">
  <Data>
    <UserDefinedRowId>9</UserDefinedRowId>
    <Company_x0020_Name>test 3</Company_x0020_Name>
    <Company_x0020_Line_x0020_2/>
    <Address>123</Address>
    <Address_x0020_Line_x0020_2/>
    <City-State-Zip/>
    <Phone_x0020_1>308.425.6039</Phone_x0020_1>
    <Phone_x0020_2/>
    <Email>info@test.com</Email>
    <Website_x0020__x0028_FULL_x0020_URL_x0029_>http://www.google.com/</Website_x0020__x0028_FULL_x0020_URL_x0029_>
    <Category>Advertising</Category>
    <Created_x0020_by>SuperUser Account</Created_x0020_by>
    <Created_x0020_at>2015-12-23T11:03:14-06:00</Created_x0020_at>
    <Changed_x0020_by>SuperUser Account</Changed_x0020_by>
    <Changed_x0020_at>2015-12-23T15:28:39-06:00</Changed_x0020_at>
    <Created_x0020_by_UDT_Original>host</Created_x0020_by_UDT_Original>
    <Created_x0020_by_UDT_Caption>SuperUser Account</Created_x0020_by_UDT_Caption>
    <Created_x0020_at_UDT_Value>&lt;!--063586465394--&gt;12/23/2015 11:03 AM</Created_x0020_at_UDT_Value>
    <Created_x0020_at_UDT_Ticks>635864653940000000</Created_x0020_at_UDT_Ticks>
    <Changed_x0020_by_UDT_Original>host</Changed_x0020_by_UDT_Original>
    <Changed_x0020_by_UDT_Caption>SuperUser Account</Changed_x0020_by_UDT_Caption>
    <Changed_x0020_at_UDT_Value>&lt;!--063586481319--&gt;12/23/2015 3:28 PM</Changed_x0020_at_UDT_Value>
    <Changed_x0020_at_UDT_Ticks>635864813190000000</Changed_x0020_at_UDT_Ticks>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <UserDefinedRowId>10</UserDefinedRowId>
    <Company_x0020_Name>test 2</Company_x0020_Name>
    <Company_x0020_Line_x0020_2/>
    <Address/>
    <Address_x0020_Line_x0020_2/>
    <City-State-Zip/>
    <Phone_x0020_1>308.425.3654</Phone_x0020_1>
    <Phone_x0020_2/>
    <Email/>
    <Website_x0020__x0028_FULL_x0020_URL_x0029_/>
    <Category>Abstractor</Category>
    <Created_x0020_by>SuperUser Account</Created_x0020_by>
    <Created_x0020_at>2015-12-23T11:08:19-06:00</Created_x0020_at>
    <Changed_x0020_by>SuperUser Account</Changed_x0020_by>
    <Changed_x0020_at>2015-12-23T15:28:19-06:00</Changed_x0020_at>
    <Created_x0020_by_UDT_Original>host</Created_x0020_by_UDT_Original>
    <Created_x0020_by_UDT_Caption>SuperUser Account</Created_x0020_by_UDT_Caption>
    <Created_x0020_at_UDT_Value>&lt;!--063586465699--&gt;12/23/2015 11:08 AM</Created_x0020_at_UDT_Value>
    <Created_x0020_at_UDT_Ticks>635864656990000000</Created_x0020_at_UDT_Ticks>
    <Changed_x0020_by_UDT_Original>host</Changed_x0020_by_UDT_Original>
    <Changed_x0020_by_UDT_Caption>SuperUser Account</Changed_x0020_by_UDT_Caption>
    <Changed_x0020_at_UDT_Value>&lt;!--063586481299--&gt;12/23/2015 3:28 PM</Changed_x0020_at_UDT_Value>
    <Changed_x0020_at_UDT_Ticks>635864812990000000</Changed_x0020_at_UDT_Ticks>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <UserDefinedRowId>11</UserDefinedRowId>
    <Company_x0020_Name>test</Company_x0020_Name>
    <Company_x0020_Line_x0020_2/>
    <Address/>
    <Address_x0020_Line_x0020_2/>
    <City-State-Zip/>
    <Phone_x0020_1/>
    <Phone_x0020_2/>
    <Email/>
    <Website_x0020__x0028_FULL_x0020_URL_x0029_/>
    <Category>Abstractor;Antiques &amp; Collectibles</Category>
    <Created_x0020_by>SuperUser Account</Created_x0020_by>
    <Created_x0020_at>2015-12-23T14:20:21-06:00</Created_x0020_at>
    <Changed_x0020_by>SuperUser Account</Changed_x0020_by>
    <Changed_x0020_at>2015-12-23T14:20:21-06:00</Changed_x0020_at>
    <Created_x0020_by_UDT_Original>host</Created_x0020_by_UDT_Original>
    <Created_x0020_by_UDT_Caption>SuperUser Account</Created_x0020_by_UDT_Caption>
    <Created_x0020_at_UDT_Value>&lt;!--063586477221--&gt;12/23/2015 2:20 PM</Created_x0020_at_UDT_Value>
    <Created_x0020_at_UDT_Ticks>635864772210000000</Created_x0020_at_UDT_Ticks>
    <Changed_x0020_by_UDT_Original>host</Changed_x0020_by_UDT_Original>
    <Changed_x0020_by_UDT_Caption>SuperUser Account</Changed_x0020_by_UDT_Caption>
    <Changed_x0020_at_UDT_Value>&lt;!--063586477221--&gt;12/23/2015 2:20 PM</Changed_x0020_at_UDT_Value>
    <Changed_x0020_at_UDT_Ticks>635864772210000000</Changed_x0020_at_UDT_Ticks>
  </Data>
  <Fields>
    <UserDefinedFieldId>22</UserDefinedFieldId>
    <ModuleID>447</ModuleID>
    <FieldTitle>Company Name</FieldTitle>
    <Required>true</Required>
    <FieldOrder>0</FieldOrder>
    <FieldType>String</FieldType>
    <Visible>true</Visible>
    <ShowOnEdit>true</ShowOnEdit>
    <Searchable>true</Searchable>
    <PrivateField>false</PrivateField>
    <MultipleValues>false</MultipleValues>
    <NormalizeFlag>false</NormalizeFlag>
    <ValueColumn>Company_x0020_Name</ValueColumn>
    <SortColumn>Company_x0020_Name</SortColumn>
  </Fields>
  <Fields>
    <UserDefinedFieldId>23</UserDefinedFieldId>
    <ModuleID>447</ModuleID>
    <FieldTitle>Company Line 2</FieldTitle>
    <Required>false</Required>
    <FieldOrder>1</FieldOrder>
    <FieldType>String</FieldType>
    <Visible>true</Visible>
    <ShowOnEdit>true</ShowOnEdit>
    <Searchable>true</Searchable>
    <PrivateField>false</PrivateField>
    <MultipleValues>false</MultipleValues>
    <NormalizeFlag>false</NormalizeFlag>
    <ValueColumn>Company_x0020_Line_x0020_2</ValueColumn>
    <SortColumn>Company_x0020_Line_x0020_2</SortColumn>
  </Fields>
  <Fields>
    <UserDefinedFieldId>24</UserDefinedFieldId>
    <ModuleID>447</ModuleID>
    <FieldTitle>Address</FieldTitle>
    <Required>false</Required>
    <FieldOrder>2</FieldOrder>
    <FieldType>String</FieldType>
    <Visible>true</Visible>
    <ShowOnEdit>true</ShowOnEdit>
    <Searchable>false</Searchable>
    <PrivateField>false</PrivateField>
    <MultipleValues>false</MultipleValues>
    <NormalizeFlag>false</NormalizeFlag>
    <ValueColumn>Address</ValueColumn>
    <SortColumn>Address</SortColumn>
  </Fields>
  <Fields>
    <UserDefinedFieldId>25</UserDefinedFieldId>
    <ModuleID>447</ModuleID>
    <FieldTitle>Address Line 2</FieldTitle>
    <Required>false</Required>
    <FieldOrder>3</FieldOrder>
    <FieldType>String</FieldType>
    <Visible>true</Visible>
    <ShowOnEdit>true</ShowOnEdit>
    <Searchable>false</Searchable>
    <PrivateField>false</PrivateField>
    <MultipleValues>false</MultipleValues>
    <NormalizeFlag>false</NormalizeFlag>
    <ValueColumn>Address_x0020_Line_x0020_2</ValueColumn>
    <SortColumn>Address_x0020_Line_x0020_2</SortColumn>
  </Fields>
  <Fields>
    <UserDefinedFieldId>26</UserDefinedFieldId>
    <ModuleID>447</ModuleID>
    <FieldTitle>City-State-Zip</FieldTitle>
    <Required>false</Required>
    <FieldOrder>4</FieldOrder>
    <FieldType>String</FieldType>
    <Visible>true</Visible>
    <ShowOnEdit>true</ShowOnEdit>
    <Searchable>false</Searchable>
    <PrivateField>false</PrivateField>
    <MultipleValues>false</MultipleValues>
    <NormalizeFlag>false</NormalizeFlag>
    <ValueColumn>City-State-Zip</ValueColumn>
    <SortColumn>City-State-Zip</SortColumn>
  </Fields>
  <Fields>
    <UserDefinedFieldId>27</UserDefinedFieldId>
    <ModuleID>447</ModuleID>
    <FieldTitle>Phone 1</FieldTitle>
    <Required>false</Required>
    <FieldOrder>5</FieldOrder>
    <FieldType>String</FieldType>
    <Visible>true</Visible>
    <ShowOnEdit>true</ShowOnEdit>
    <Searchable>false</Searchable>
    <PrivateField>false</PrivateField>
    <MultipleValues>false</MultipleValues>
    <NormalizeFlag>false</NormalizeFlag>
    <ValueColumn>Phone_x0020_1</ValueColumn>
    <SortColumn>Phone_x0020_1</SortColumn>
  </Fields>
  <Fields>
    <UserDefinedFieldId>28</UserDefinedFieldId>
    <ModuleID>447</ModuleID>
    <FieldTitle>Phone 2</FieldTitle>
    <Required>false</Required>
    <FieldOrder>6</FieldOrder>
    <FieldType>String</FieldType>
    <Visible>true</Visible>
    <ShowOnEdit>true</ShowOnEdit>
    <Searchable>false</Searchable>
    <PrivateField>false</PrivateField>
    <MultipleValues>false</MultipleValues>
    <NormalizeFlag>false</NormalizeFlag>
    <ValueColumn>Phone_x0020_2</ValueColumn>
    <SortColumn>Phone_x0020_2</SortColumn>
  </Fields>
  <Fields>
    <UserDefinedFieldId>29</UserDefinedFieldId>
    <ModuleID>447</ModuleID>
    <FieldTitle>Email</FieldTitle>
    <Required>false</Required>
    <FieldOrder>7</FieldOrder>
    <FieldType>String</FieldType>
    <Visible>true</Visible>
    <ShowOnEdit>true</ShowOnEdit>
    <Searchable>false</Searchable>
    <PrivateField>false</PrivateField>
    <MultipleValues>false</MultipleValues>
    <NormalizeFlag>false</NormalizeFlag>
    <ValueColumn>Email</ValueColumn>
    <SortColumn>Email</SortColumn>
  </Fields>
  <Fields>
    <UserDefinedFieldId>30</UserDefinedFieldId>
    <ModuleID>447</ModuleID>
    <FieldTitle>Website (FULL URL)</FieldTitle>
    <Required>false</Required>
    <FieldOrder>8</FieldOrder>
    <FieldType>String</FieldType>
    <Visible>true</Visible>
    <ShowOnEdit>true</ShowOnEdit>
    <Searchable>false</Searchable>
    <PrivateField>false</PrivateField>
    <MultipleValues>false</MultipleValues>
    <NormalizeFlag>false</NormalizeFlag>
    <ValueColumn>Website_x0020__x0028_FULL_x0020_URL_x0029_</ValueColumn>
    <SortColumn>Website_x0020__x0028_FULL_x0020_URL_x0029_</SortColumn>
  </Fields>
  <Fields>
    <UserDefinedFieldId>21</UserDefinedFieldId>
    <ModuleID>447</ModuleID>
    <FieldTitle>Category</FieldTitle>
    <Required>true</Required>
    <FieldOrder>9</FieldOrder>
    <FieldType>String</FieldType>
    <Visible>true</Visible>
    <ShowOnEdit>true</ShowOnEdit>
    <Searchable>false</Searchable>
    <PrivateField>false</PrivateField>
    <MultipleValues>true</MultipleValues>
    <InputSettings>Abstractor;Advertising;Agricultural;Antiques &amp; Collectibles;Apparel;Appliances;Attorneys;Auctioneers;Auto;Bakeries;Banks;Beauty Shops;Bulldozing, Road Construction, Heavy Equipment;Business &amp; Computer Services;Cable and Internet;Carpentry;Carpet, Flooring and Installation;Carwash;Cellular Phone;Certified Public Accountants;Chiropractor;Churches;Community Services;Convenience Stores;Crafts;Day Care;Dental;Drug Store;Dry Cleaners &amp; Laundry;Education;Electrical;Farm &amp; Ranch Supply;Fast Food &amp; Take Out;Fertilizer, Feed, Seed &amp; Chemicals;Firearms;Flower Shop;Furniture;Gift Shops;Graphic Design;Grocery;Handyman/General Repair;Hardware;Health, Home &amp; Beauty Products;Heating;Hunting Outfitters;Insurance;Karaoke Services;Lawn Care;Lawn Equipment;Lodging;Lumber Yards;Manicures &amp; Pedicures;Massage;Meat;Medical;Mini-Storage;Mortuary;Newspaper;Nurseries &amp; Greenhouses;Optometrist;Pet Supplies;Pharmacy;Photographer;Physical Therapy;Plumbing;Preschools;Printing;Property Maintenance;Public Schools;Quilting;Recreation;Restaurants;Senior Services;Sewing &amp; Quilt Making;T-Shirts;Taverns;Theaters;Thrift Shop;Tires;Toys;Truck and Trailer Repair;Trucking;Utilities;Variety Stores;Veterinarians;Well Drilling-[[vRBL]]</InputSettings>
    <NormalizeFlag>false</NormalizeFlag>
    <ValueColumn>Category</ValueColumn>
    <SortColumn>Category</SortColumn>
  </Fields>
  <Fields>
    <UserDefinedFieldId>20</UserDefinedFieldId>
    <ModuleID>447</ModuleID>
    <FieldTitle>Created by</FieldTitle>
    <Required>true</Required>
    <FieldOrder>10</FieldOrder>
    <FieldType>CreatedBy</FieldType>
    <Visible>false</Visible>
    <ShowOnEdit>false</ShowOnEdit>
    <Searchable>false</Searchable>
    <PrivateField>false</PrivateField>
    <MultipleValues>false</MultipleValues>
    <NormalizeFlag>false</NormalizeFlag>
    <ValueColumn>Created_x0020_by</ValueColumn>
    <SortColumn>Created_x0020_by</SortColumn>
  </Fields>
  <Fields>
    <UserDefinedFieldId>19</UserDefinedFieldId>
    <ModuleID>447</ModuleID>
    <FieldTitle>Created at</FieldTitle>
    <Required>true</Required>
    <FieldOrder>11</FieldOrder>
    <FieldType>CreatedAt</FieldType>
    <Visible>false</Visible>
    <ShowOnEdit>false</ShowOnEdit>
    <Searchable>false</Searchable>
    <PrivateField>false</PrivateField>
    <MultipleValues>false</MultipleValues>
    <NormalizeFlag>false</NormalizeFlag>
    <ValueColumn>Created_x0020_at_UDT_Value</ValueColumn>
    <SortColumn>Created_x0020_at</SortColumn>
  </Fields>
  <Fields>
    <UserDefinedFieldId>18</UserDefinedFieldId>
    <ModuleID>447</ModuleID>
    <FieldTitle>Changed by</FieldTitle>
    <Required>true</Required>
    <FieldOrder>12</FieldOrder>
    <FieldType>ChangedBy</FieldType>
    <Visible>false</Visible>
    <ShowOnEdit>false</ShowOnEdit>
    <Searchable>false</Searchable>
    <PrivateField>false</PrivateField>
    <MultipleValues>false</MultipleValues>
    <NormalizeFlag>false</NormalizeFlag>
    <ValueColumn>Changed_x0020_by</ValueColumn>
    <SortColumn>Changed_x0020_by</SortColumn>
  </Fields>
  <Fields>
    <UserDefinedFieldId>17</UserDefinedFieldId>
    <ModuleID>447</ModuleID>
    <FieldTitle>Changed at</FieldTitle>
    <Required>true</Required>
    <FieldOrder>13</FieldOrder>
    <FieldType>ChangedAt</FieldType>
    <Visible>false</Visible>
    <ShowOnEdit>false</ShowOnEdit>
    <Searchable>false</Searchable>
    <PrivateField>false</PrivateField>
    <MultipleValues>false</MultipleValues>
    <NormalizeFlag>false</NormalizeFlag>
    <ValueColumn>Changed_x0020_at_UDT_Value</ValueColumn>
    <SortColumn>Changed_x0020_at</SortColumn>
  </Fields>
  <FieldSettings>
    <FieldId>30</FieldId>
    <SettingName>Abbreviate</SettingName>
    <SettingValue>False</SettingValue>
  </FieldSettings>
  <FieldSettings>
    <FieldId>30</FieldId>
    <SettingName>EnforceDownload</SettingName>
    <SettingValue>False</SettingValue>
  </FieldSettings>
  <FieldSettings>
    <FieldId>30</FieldId>
    <SettingName>ShowOpenInNewWindow</SettingName>
    <SettingValue>False</SettingValue>
  </FieldSettings>
  <FieldSettings>
    <FieldId>30</FieldId>
    <SettingName>TrackDownloads</SettingName>
    <SettingValue>False</SettingValue>
  </FieldSettings>
  <Context>
    <ModuleId>447</ModuleId>
    <TabId>100</TabId>
    <TabName>Merchants</TabName>
    <PortalId>0</PortalId>
    <UserName>host</UserName>
    <BestUserName>SuperUser Account</BestUserName>
    <DisplayName>SuperUser Account</DisplayName>
    <ApplicationPath/>
    <HomePath>/Portals/0/</HomePath>
    <UserRoles>||All Users|Administrators|</UserRoles>
    <IsAdministratorRole>true</IsAdministratorRole>
    <Parameter/>
    <OrderBy>UserDefinedRowId</OrderBy>
    <OrderDirection>ascending</OrderDirection>
    <CurrentCulture>en-US</CurrentCulture>
    <LocalizedString_Search>Search</LocalizedString_Search>
    <LocalizedString_Page>Page</LocalizedString_Page>
    <LocalizedString_Of> of </LocalizedString_Of>
    <LocalizedString_First>First</LocalizedString_First>
    <LocalizedString_Previous>Previous</LocalizedString_Previous>
    <LocalizedString_Next>Next</LocalizedString_Next>
    <LocalizedString_Last>Last</LocalizedString_Last>
    <NowInTicks>635864813985230000</NowInTicks>
    <TodayInTicks>635864256000000000</TodayInTicks>
    <TicksPerDay>864000000000</TicksPerDay>
    <LocalizedDate>12/23/2015 3:29 PM</LocalizedDate>
    <Now>2015-12-23T15:29:58.523-06:00</Now>
  </Context>
</UserDefinedTable>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:udt="DotNetNuke/UserDefinedTable" exclude-result-prefixes="udt">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <!--
  This prefix is used to generate module specific query strings
  Each querystring or form value that starts with udt_{ModuleId}_param 
  will be added as parameter starting with param
  -->
  <xsl:variable name="prefix_param">udt_<xsl:value-of select="//udt:Context/udt:ModuleId" />_param</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:param name="param_orderby" select="//udt:Fields[udt:UserDefinedFieldId=//udt:Context/udt:OrderBy]/udt:SortColumn" />
  <xsl:param name="param_direction" select="//udt:Context/udt:OrderDirection" />
  <!--wrong string would break stylesheet, so fallback to ascending if userinput is wrong-->
  <xsl:variable name="orderDirection">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$param_direction='descending'">
        <xsl:text>descending</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>ascending</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="orderType">
    <xsl:variable name="DataType" select="//udt:Fields[udt:SortColumn=$param_orderby]/udt:FieldType" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$DataType='Int32' or $DataType='Decimal' or $DataType='Currency'">number</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>text</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="udt:Data" mode="list">
    <div class="dnnGridItem">
      <xsl:call-template name="EditLink" />;
      <xsl:value-of select="udt:Company_x0020_Name" disable-output-escaping="yes" />;
      <xsl:value-of select="udt:Company_x0020_Line_x0020_2" disable-output-escaping="yes" />;
      <xsl:value-of select="udt:Address" disable-output-escaping="yes" />;
      <xsl:value-of select="udt:Address_x0020_Line_x0020_2" disable-output-escaping="yes" />;
      <xsl:value-of select="udt:City-State-Zip" disable-output-escaping="yes" />;
      <xsl:value-of select="udt:Phone_x0020_1" disable-output-escaping="yes" />;
      <xsl:value-of select="udt:Phone_x0020_2" disable-output-escaping="yes" />;
      <xsl:value-of select="udt:Email" disable-output-escaping="yes" />;
      <xsl:value-of select="udt:Website_x0020__x0028_FULL_x0020_URL_x0029_" disable-output-escaping="yes" />;
      <xsl:value-of select="udt:Category" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/udt:UserDefinedTable">
    <xsl:variable name="currentData" select="udt:Data" />
    <xsl:if test="$currentData">
      <!-- DEFINE ANY HEADERS HERE, EXAMPLE IS FOR TABLE TYPE LISTING -->
      <!-- Parameter header is optional! -->
      <!--
      <tr class="dnnGridHeader">
        <td/>
        <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates select ="udt:Fields[udt:FieldTitle='NameOfColumn']">
            <xsl:with-param name ="header" select ="NewHeaderName"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </td>...
      </tr>
      -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentData" mode="list">
        <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$param_orderby]" order="{$orderDirection}" data-type="{$orderType}" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="udt:Fields" name="SortingHeader">
    <xsl:param name="header" select="udt:FieldTitle" />
    <xsl:if test="udt:Visible='true' or udt:Visible='True'">
      <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="udt:ValueColumn=$param_orderby">
              <xsl:variable name="flippedDirection">
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="$orderDirection='ascending'">
                    <xsl:text>descending</xsl:text>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>ascending</xsl:text>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:variable>
      ?<xsl:value-of select="$prefix_param" />_orderby=<xsl:value-of select="udt:ValueColumn" />&amp;<xsl:value-of select="$prefix_param" />_direction=<xsl:value-of select="$flippedDirection" /></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              ?<xsl:value-of select="$prefix_param" />_orderby=<xsl:value-of select="udt:ValueColumn" />&amp;<xsl:value-of select="$prefix_param" />_direction=<xsl:value-of select="$orderDirection" /></xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <!--flipped order direction-->
        <xsl:value-of select="$header" />
        <xsl:if test="udt:ValueColumn=$param_orderby">
          <img src="{//udt:Context/udt:ApplicationPath}/images/sort{$orderDirection}.gif" border="0" />
        </xsl:if>
      </a>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="EditLink">
    <xsl:if test="udt:EditLink">
      <a href="{udt:EditLink}">
        <img border="0" alt="edit" src="{//udt:Context/udt:ApplicationPath}/images/edit.gif" />
      </a>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
<udt:template listType="div" delimiter=";" listView="&lt;div class=&quot;dnnGridItem&quot;&gt;[UDT:EditLink];&#xD;&#xA;[Company Name];&#xD;&#xA;[Company Line 2];&#xD;&#xA;[Address];&#xD;&#xA;[Address Line 2];&#xD;&#xA;[City-State-Zip];&#xD;&#xA;[Phone 1];&#xD;&#xA;[Phone 2];&#xD;&#xA;[Email];&#xD;&#xA;[Website (FULL URL)];&#xD;&#xA;[Category]&lt;/div&gt;" headerView="" detailView="[UDT:ListView][UDT:EditLink]&#xD;&#xA;&lt;table&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;normalBold&quot;&gt;Company Name&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;Normal&quot;&gt;[Company Name]&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;/tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;normalBold&quot;&gt;Company Line 2&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;Normal&quot;&gt;[Company Line 2]&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;/tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;normalBold&quot;&gt;Address&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;Normal&quot;&gt;[Address]&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;/tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;normalBold&quot;&gt;Address Line 2&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;Normal&quot;&gt;[Address Line 2]&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;/tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;normalBold&quot;&gt;City-State-Zip&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;Normal&quot;&gt;[City-State-Zip]&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;/tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;normalBold&quot;&gt;Phone 1&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;Normal&quot;&gt;[Phone 1]&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;/tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;normalBold&quot;&gt;Phone 2&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;Normal&quot;&gt;[Phone 2]&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;/tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;normalBold&quot;&gt;Email&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;Normal&quot;&gt;[Email]&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;/tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;normalBold&quot;&gt;Website&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;Normal&quot;&gt;[Website]&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;/tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;normalBold&quot;&gt;Category&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;Normal&quot;&gt;[Category]&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;/tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;normalBold&quot;&gt;Created by&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;Normal&quot;&gt;[Created by]&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;/tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;normalBold&quot;&gt;Created at&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;Normal&quot;&gt;[Created at_UDT_Value]&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;/tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;normalBold&quot;&gt;Changed by&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;Normal&quot;&gt;[Changed by]&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;/tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;normalBold&quot;&gt;Changed at&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;td class=&quot;Normal&quot;&gt;[Changed at_UDT_Value]&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;/tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/table&gt;" trackingEmail="" sorting="true" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

CATEGORY 1

- Business 1, Address, Phone...
- Business 2, Address, Phone...
- Business 3, Address, Phone...
- Business 4, Address, Phone...

-

CATEGORY 2

- Business 2, Address, Phone...
- Business 5, Address, Phone...
- Business 6, Address, Phone...

-

CATEGORY 3

- Business 1, Address, Phone...
- Business 4, Address, Phone...
- Business 7, Address, Phone...

Comment: Could you please (a) minimize the example to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem and (b) post the exact output you want as the result of transforming the given input?

Comment: Sorry it was too much info! I wasn't exactly sure what portions would be needed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule, grouping in XSLT 1.0 is achieved using a method known as **Muenchian grouping**. The basics of the method are explained here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

In your case, the problem is complicated first by companies having multiple categories, and further by having the categories listed in a semicolon-separated list (instead of individual elements, as would be the norm for a well-designed XML document).

This means you need to process the input in two passes:

1. First, each company needs to be tokenized to create a separately
   addressable node for each one of its categories;
2. Next, we'll apply Muenchian grouping to the result of the first pass,
   creating a group for each distinct category and list the companies
   in that category.

For demonstrating the process, I will be using the following minimized input:

**XML**

```
<UserDefinedTable xmlns="DotNetNuke/UserDefinedTable">
   <Data>
      <Company_Name>Alpha</Company_Name>
      <Address>123</Address>
      <Phone>308.425.6031</Phone>
      <Category>Red;Green</Category>
   </Data>
   <Data>
      <Company_Name>Bravo</Company_Name>
      <Address>45</Address>
      <Phone>308.425.3652</Phone>
      <Category>Green;Blue</Category>
   </Data>
   <Data>
      <Company_Name>Charlie</Company_Name>
      <Address>678</Address>
      <Phone>308.425.7293</Phone>
      <Category>Blue;Red</Category>
   </Data>
</UserDefinedTable>
```

Applying the folowing stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:udt="DotNetNuke/UserDefinedTable" 
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
exclude-result-prefixes="udt exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="company-by-category" match="company" use="category" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- first pass: tokenize companies by category -->
    <xsl:variable name="first-pass">
        <xsl:for-each select="udt:UserDefinedTable/udt:Data">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="first-pass-set" select="exsl:node-set($first-pass)" />
    <!-- output -->
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$first-pass-set/company[count(. | key('company-by-category', category)[1]) = 1]"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="company">
    <div>
        <h3><xsl:value-of select="category"/></h3>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('company-by-category', category)" mode="list"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="company" mode="list">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/><br/>
        <xsl:value-of select="address"/><br/>
        <xsl:value-of select="phone"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="udt:Category"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="';'"/>
    <company>
        <name><xsl:value-of select="udt:Company_Name"/></name>
        <address><xsl:value-of select="udt:Address"/></address>
        <phone><xsl:value-of select="udt:Phone"/></phone>
        <category><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/></category>
    </company>
    <!-- recursive call -->
     <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce the following result:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div>
         <h3>Red</h3>
         <p>Alpha<br/>123<br/>308.425.6031</p>
         <p>Charlie<br/>678<br/>308.425.7293</p>
      </div>
      <div>
         <h3>Green</h3>
         <p>Alpha<br/>123<br/>308.425.6031</p>
         <p>Bravo<br/>45<br/>308.425.3652</p>
      </div>
      <div>
         <h3>Blue</h3>
         <p>Bravo<br/>45<br/>308.425.3652</p>
         <p>Charlie<br/>678<br/>308.425.7293</p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

rendered as:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! I had tried bits and pieces of that but would never have gotten to the point where I could get it all combined. It worked perfectly to sort everything into categories. I can handle the rest of the styling so I'm good to go from here. You're a life saver! Thanks!